# Sharing useState between different components ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

So I've been trying to make a booking system, each user can only book once the problem being how to check which user is logged in.

The component LoginForm has the following useState:

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState({ room: "", password: "" });
```

Is there anyway to import the useState to another component? If not is there anyway to to check which user is logged in?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question but for what it's worth, you can try [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) so that you can access something like `details` in another component without passing it down the tree.

Comment: It seems that your question is more about "how to persist a user's `login` state across the app" rather than "how to share `useState` value between components." While it's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish without specific code examples, you might want to consider `useContext` or a third-party authentication library as a starter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have seen, There are 2 approaches to store userdetails in the react application,

**Approach 1:**

You can store the user details in the `contextApi` and use it accross the application by using the context. You can use `createContext` to create a context and `useContext` to use it accross the application. Use the below react js documentation link for the reference,

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

**Approach 2:**

This is the easiest approach. You can also use the `localStorage` to store the user details and retrieve on any page you want from `localStorage`.

To store the userdetails in the `localStorage`. Use the below code,

```
localStorage.setItem("userDetails", {username, email, mobileno});
```

To retrieve the userdetails from the `localStorage`. You can use the below code,

```
let userdetails = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
```

**Note :**

You should not store passwords in both the approaches.